# Images using Glide are blurry

Tags: java, android, android-layout, picasso, android-glide

I'm trying to use Glide to display images in a Recyclerview but they are blurred (the images are in jpg format).

I've tried using Picasso to display them but I get exactly the same issue: the images are blurred. As a test, I also have 10 drawables and these seem to display just fine. Does anyone know why the images are blurred?

** EDIT **

I just ran my code on a (Genymotion emulator) Google Galaxy Nexus 4.2.2; API 17 and the images are fine! So the next issue is why the images were blurred on a (Genymotion emulator) Motorola Moto X 4.3 ; API 18.

** EDIT **

I think i've found out why my images were blurry:
In my main fragment I wrote the URL of my images to my database via my custom Content Provider. My initial images were of a lower resolution therefore when I displayed them and due to resizing and formatting they became blurry. I therefore used an image of higher resolution in the hope this would resolve the issue. It did not, initially (frustration!!), until I changed the database version number. The new images were then written to the database and the issue was correct.

```
package demo.example.com.customarrayadapter;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;

import java.util.List;

import demo.example.com.customarrayadapter.data.FlavorsContract;

/**
 * Created by richard on 03/01/16.
 */
public class AndroidFlavorCursorRecyclerViewAdapter extends
        CursorRecyclerAdapter<AndroidFlavorCursorRecyclerViewAdapter
        .DataObjectHolder> {
    private static String LOG_TAG = AndroidFlavorCursorRecyclerViewAdapter.class.getSimpleName();
    private List<AndroidFlavor> mDataset;
    private static MyClickListener myClickListener;
    private Cursor mCursor;
    private int posterHeight;
    private int posterWidth;

    public static class DataObjectHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
            implements View
            .OnClickListener {
        TextView label;
        ImageView image;

        public DataObjectHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            //label = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.flavor_text);
            image = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.flavor_image);
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Adding Listener");
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            myClickListener.onItemClick(getPosition(), v);
        }
    }

    public void setOnItemClickListener(MyClickListener myClickListener) {
        this.myClickListener = myClickListener;
    }

    public AndroidFlavorCursorRecyclerViewAdapter(Cursor cursor, int w, int h) {
        super(cursor);
        //mCursor = cursor;
        posterHeight = h;
        posterWidth = w;
    }

    @Override
    public DataObjectHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                               int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.flavor_item, parent, false);

        DataObjectHolder dataObjectHolder = new DataObjectHolder(view);
        return dataObjectHolder;
    }


    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolderCursor(DataObjectHolder holder, Cursor cursor) {
        Context context = holder.image.getContext();

        //Log.i(LOG_TAG,"image:" + cursor.getString(
        //        cursor.getColumnIndex(FlavorsContract.FlavorEntry.COLUMN_FILM_POSTER)));

        //holder.label.setText(cursor.getString(
        //        cursor.getColumnIndex(FlavorsContract.FlavorEntry.COLUMN_VERSION_NAME)));
        String url = cursor.getString(
                cursor.getColumnIndex(FlavorsContract.FlavorEntry.COLUMN_FILM_POSTER));
        Glide.with(context.getApplicationContext()).load(url)
                .into(holder.image);

        //Picasso.with(context).load("http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png")
        //        .into(holder.image);

        Log.v(LOG_TAG, "onBindViewHolderCursor() " + cursor.getCount());
    }

    //    public void addItem(AndroidFlavor dataObj, int index) {
    //    mDataset.add(dataObj);
    //    notifyItemInserted(index);
    //}

    //public void deleteItem(int index) {
    //    mDataset.remove(index);
    //    notifyItemRemoved(index);
    //}

    //@Override
    //public int getItemCount() {
    //    return mDataset.size();
    //}

    public interface MyClickListener {
        public void onItemClick(int position, View v);
    }

}
```

I thought it might be a good idea to put my imageview:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
   >

        <demo.example.com.customarrayadapter.SquareImageView
            android:id="@+id/flavor_image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            />

</FrameLayout>
```

SquareImageView class:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class SquareImageView extends ImageView
{
    public SquareImageView(Context context)
    {
        super(context);
    }

    public SquareImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public SquareImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle)
    {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec)
    {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        setMeasuredDimension(getMeasuredWidth(), getMeasuredWidth()*2); //Snap to width

    }
}
```

Comment: Wow! It's awesome that my post has been viewed 21 times but can anyone help. If you require more infomation guys i'd be glad to give it.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is clear but did you try those emulators only ? 
And why didn't i find the .size() nowhere ?

Are you sure your picture has been resized and not formated only to be seen entirely ?

If yes, try to look at your console. Did you see an error like this ?

```
W/OpenGLRenderer: Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture
```

Comment: Sorry, i'm unsure what you mean by .size()

Comment: I'm  unsure what you mean by .size() but if you are implying the number of images i'm returning from one of the many collections such as Hashmap or ArrayList(). Let me say, I am reading from a Content Provider backed by an SQLite database. So I don't need .size(). If you are implying size in respect to an image can you explain.

Answer (score 0):

myFault ! i ment .override !

After load Your picture, be sure that the picture as been properly resize before to send it in your layout container :

```
public Bitmap loadFormattedImage(Context c ,int imv_icone){
   Glide.with(c)
            .load(imv_icone)
            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
            .override(300, 200);

    return  BitmapFactory.decodeResource(c.getResources(), imv_icone);
}
```

Have you already try this ?